# REST API JAVA Empty Path Parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, get, jax-rs

I am new to REST API's.
I am developing a REST API. 
In the following API the parameters I take is cloud-id.

This is the API Call:

```
@GET
@Path("{cloud-id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Object Getall(@PathParam("cloud-id") String cloudID) {
  if(cloudID!=null){
      //return some details
  }else{
     //return something else
  }
}
```

Happy Path:

```
http://example.com/sampleCloudID
```

This also works fine

```
http://example.com/(sampleCloudID)
It gives a 404 as expected
```

But when I give the URI as

```
http://example.com/{sampleCloudID}
```

**ERROR:**

```
You specified too few path parameters in the request.
```

In case the input I receive is {samplecloudID} I expect the service to return a 404, but I am unable to reach my resource if the path variable is in {}.

Why are curly braces giving me a error but normal parenthesis give 404 as expected ?

Comment: You should use the url as the top one `http://example.com/sampleCloudID`. The brackets are only used in the code so you can add `@PathParam` as parameter to your method

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send special characters as part of the URL you need to encode them.
try using `http://example.com/%7BsampleCloudID%7D`
This should let your controller get the `{}`

[This wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) article should give you details.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) states that certain characters are unsafe in URLs:

> Unsafe:
>
> Characters can be unsafe for a number of reasons. [...] Other
> characters are unsafe because gateways and other transport agents are
> known to sometimes modify such characters. These characters are "{",
> "}", "|", "", "^", "~", "[", "]", and "`".
>
> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL. For
> example, the character "#" must be encoded within URLs even in systems
> that do not normally deal with fragment or anchor identifiers, so that
> if the URL is copied into another system that does use them, it will
> not be necessary to change the URL encoding.

source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79057/curly-brackets-in-urls?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

You could write code this way in which you did't get any error on changing type of your path variable

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/your-path/{cloud-id}", produces = "application/json")
public Object Getall(@PathVariable(value = "cloud-id", required = false) String cloudID) {

//do your stuff

}
```

Comment: the path variable cloud-id is mandatory but if i get something like {cloud-id}, I want to give a 404.
I get you solution is there other alternative for this?